# Spring Cloud Config with AWS Java SDK 2.0

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/build-serverless-aws-codecommit-workflows-using-amazon-cloudwatch-events-and-jgit/) but I'm using AWS Java SDK 2. But it fails due to missing classes that are from the 1.X version of the SDK.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials
    at com.xxx.cloud.aws.structure.StructureTest.getRepositories(StructureTest.java:244)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 38 more
```

Any hints on how to make it work for 2.X SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are significant (breaking) changes between SDK v1 and v2. v2 is not backward-compatiple which means v1-examples will not run on v2 without major changes and refactorings in the code.
Even with the [migration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/migration-guide/what-is-java-migration.html) it takes some AWS-experience to get it done.

v2 is currently a developer-preview (even if it's already pretty stable ). v1 is still the official production-release and will be fully supported by Amazon for a longer time even if the first release of v2 arrives.

This said I recommend to use v1 for completing the tutorial. As soon as you got into coding for AWS you will find it easy to express your own ideas in either v1 or v2 (because the 2 versions are functionally equivalent afaik).

Comment: Switched to v 2 since the tutorial didn't work for me as it is. I was able to convert the class to AWS v2 but still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the project from GitHub, and from the gradle file, I think they are missing:

compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: 'X'

Where 'X' is the version you are targeting to.

Comment: Might be the case but still, the answer would be a version on top of the 2.X SDK.

Comment: Well yeah, dismiss the version, I just wanted to point out that the dependency was missing. I will edit my answer. If it helps, please vote.